# AWS Amplify React app redeploy not working

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I have a react app that is deployed using AWS Amplify. It builds from the `main` branch for the repo in Github. It deploys and works properly.

However, changing to a previously deployed build and clicking the "Redeploy this version" causes Amplify to start a new build on the latest commit on the "main" branch.

Looking at the previous build(s), they do build successfully and there are artifacts available.

I would expect it to redeploy the artifact, not start a fresh build from the latest commit.

Is there a setting that controls that?

Here is the config file

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build:admin
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: packages/apps/admin/build
    files:
      - '**/*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I change my branches or create new branches, I tend to run the below commands on react app directory.

```
npm amplify init
npm install aws-amplify

npm amplify push
npm amplify pull
```

works perfectly fine for me.